# Cleaning malformed UTF-8 data

Tags: ios, swift, unicode, utf-8, nsstring

#### Background

With Swift, I'm trying to fetch HTML via `URLSession` rather than by loading it into a `WKWebView` first as I only need the HTML and none of the subresources. I'm running into a problem with certain pages that work when loaded into `WKWebView` but when loaded via `URLSession` (or even a simple `NSString(contentsOf: url, encoding String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)`) the UTF-8 conversion fails.

#### How to reproduce

This fails (prints "nil"):

`print(try? NSString(contentsOf: URL(string: "http://www.huffingtonpost.jp/techcrunch-japan/amazon-is-gobbling-whole-foods-for-a-reported-13-7-billion_b_17171132.html?utm_hp_ref=japan&ir=Japan")!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue))`

But changing the URL to the site's homepage, it succeeds:

`print(try? NSString(contentsOf: URL(string: "http://www.huffingtonpost.jp")!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue))`

#### Question

How can I "clean" the data returned by a URL that contains malformed UTF-8? I'd like to either remove or replace any invalid sequences in the malformed UTF-8 so that the rest of it can be viewed. WKWebView is able to render the page just fine (and claims it's UTF-8 content as well), as you can see by visiting the URL: http://www.huffingtonpost.jp/techcrunch-japan/amazon-is-gobbling-whole-foods-for-a-reported-13-7-billion_b_17171132.html?utm_hp_ref=japan&ir=Japan

Comment: I tried to validate that page and it seems that there is really something that isn't UTF-8 https://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.huffingtonpost.jp%2Ftechcrunch-japan%2Famazon-is-gobbling-whole-foods-for-a-reported-13-7-billion_b_17171132.html%3Futm_hp_ref%3Djapan%26ir%3DJapan&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Comment: Yes - web browsers do a good job at "making do" with malformed content; I'm looking to do the same with `URLSession`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is an approach to create a `String` from (possibly) malformed
UTF-8 data:

- Read the website contents into a `Data` object.
- Append a `0` byte to make it a "C string"
- Use `String(cString:)` for the conversion. This initializer replaces ill-formed UTF-8 code unit sequences with the Unicode replacement character (`"\u{FFFD}"`).
- Optionally: Remove all occurrences of the replacement character.

Example for the "cleaning" process:

```
var data = Data(bytes: [65, 66, 200, 67]) // malformed UTF-8

data.append(0)
let s = data.withUnsafeBytes { (p: UnsafePointer<CChar>) in String(cString: p) }
let clean = s.replacingOccurrences(of: "\u{FFFD}", with: "")

print(clean) // ABC
```

**Swift 5:**

```
var data = Data([65, 66, 200, 67]) // malformed UTF-8
data.append(0)
let s = data.withUnsafeBytes { p in
    String(cString: p.bindMemory(to: CChar.self).baseAddress!)
}
let clean = s.replacingOccurrences(of: "\u{FFFD}", with: "")
print(clean) // ABC
```

Of course this can be defined as a custom init method:

```
extension String {
    init(malformedUTF8 data: Data) {
        var data = data
        data.append(0)
        self = data.withUnsafeBytes { (p: UnsafePointer<CChar>) in
            String(cString: p).replacingOccurrences(of: "\u{FFFD}", with: "")
        }
    }
}
```

**Swift 5:**

```
extension String {
    init(malformedUTF8 data: Data) {
        var data = data
        data.append(0)
        self = data.withUnsafeBytes{ p in
            String(cString: p.bindMemory(to: CChar.self).baseAddress!)
        }.replacingOccurrences(of: "\u{FFFD}", with: "")
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
let data = Data(bytes: [65, 66, 200, 67])
let s = String(malformedUTF8: data) 
print(s) // ABC
```

The cleaning can be done more "directly" using `transcode` with

```
extension String {
    init(malformedUTF8 data: Data) {
        var utf16units = [UInt16]()
        utf16units.reserveCapacity(data.count) // A rough estimate

        _ = transcode(data.makeIterator(), from: UTF8.self, to: UTF16.self,
                      stoppingOnError: false) { code in
            if code != 0xFFFD {
                utf16units.append(code)
            }
        }

        self = String(utf16CodeUnits: utf16units, count: utf16units.count)
    }
}
```

This is essentially what  `String(cString:)`
does, compare 
[CString.swift](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/CString.swift) and
[StringCreate.swift](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/StringCreate.swift).

Yet another option is to use the `UTF8` codecs `decode()` method
and ignore errors:

```
extension String {
    init(malformedUTF8 data: Data) {
        var str = ""
        var iterator = data.makeIterator()
        var utf8codec = UTF8()
        var done = false
        while !done {
            switch utf8codec.decode(&iterator) {
            case .emptyInput:
                done = true
            case let .scalarValue(val):
                str.unicodeScalars.append(val)
            case .error:
                break // ignore errors
            }
        }
        self = str
    }
}
```

Comment: It works! Fantastic, thank you. I had spent hours on false starts on this.

Comment: The `utf8.decode` works perfectly. Is there a way to do so with big5?

Comment: @KimiChiu: I don't think so.

Comment: I get this warning: `'withUnsafeBytes' is deprecated: use 'withUnsafeBytes<R>(_: (UnsafeRawBufferPointer) throws -> R) rethrows -> R' instead`.

Comment: @MartinR: Thank you so much for your speedy update!!